# Reflection in Factory a Good Practice?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I wanted to write a factory which instantiates a concrete class and return its interface to the client. In this way I can decouple the client from having dependancy on the concrete class directly. But, at the same time I don't want factory to have dependancy on the concrete class. I can use Reflection to satisfy my need but before doing so I want to know whether this is a good practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard to say without more specifics, but I'd usually *expect* a factory implementation to have a dependency on the concrete class it's creating instances of. It's a perfectly natural dependency, in my view.

If you want to make it a very *general* factory which essentially adds value precisely *because* it uses reflection - in essence doing a small part of what most IoC containers do - then that's fine; but if it's a factory for one specific type, then I'd just take the dependency. It's likely to lead to code which is simpler to understand and test, as well as rather more efficient.

Comment: I would just like to add, that quite often, this factory will be in same assembly as concrete type it creates.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I understood your point. I wanted to create a general factory which decouples whole Business Layer from the UI Layer. In such as case, I can expose a general factory which is capable of instantiating any concrete class or I can expose a factory which instantiates concrete classes of certain category and I will have a factory for each category. what would be a good idea?

Comment: @Imran: Do you definitely *need* your own factoring anyway? Do existing IoC containers not do what you need? (They may not, but it's worth thinking about...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have not done enough study to know about IoC containers. But for the moment, I see Spring.NET is a good choice. Could you suggest any other framework?

Comment: @Imran: I can't say I've got enough "real" experience with .NET containers to say. I know there are plenty to choose from :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach will be good practice. But there are already frameworks that does the work for you. See the [MEF](http://bit.ly/OhgfFa) framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is nice and I don't see any problem with it. But, rather than investing time to do that, you should use some already existing frameworks.

You can consider [Spring Framework's IOC module](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html).